# Boost cannot find future::then from demo

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

I wanted to try boost future then, I have boost 1.55 installed and included in make file and I wanted to try official demo

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE

#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>

using namespace boost;

int main()
{
  future<int> f1 = async([]() { return 123; });
  future<int> f2 = f1.then([](future<int> f) { return f.get();} );// here .get() won't block });
}
```

but I always get error during compilation

```
error: ‘class boost::future<int>’ has no member named ‘then’
```

When I commented line with f2 it compiles.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should define

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_VERSION 4
```

or

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE_CONTINUATION
```